# Cannot use daisyui in tailwind, and npm install not installing

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, tailwind-css, npm-install

I was trying to install DaisyUI, by `npm i daisyui`, it gives me an error:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-reconciler@0.23.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm WARN     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm WARN     4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm WARN   35 more (@emotion/styled, @mui/base, @mui/icons-material, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-reconciler@0.23.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-reconciler
npm WARN   react-reconciler@"^0.23.0" from @react-pdf/renderer@2.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-reconciler@0.23.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-reconciler
npm WARN     react-reconciler@"^0.23.0" from @react-pdf/renderer@2.1.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.8.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.8.0" from @mui/system@5.8.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.8.1" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   34 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-tradingview-widget
npm ERR!   react-tradingview-widget@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-tradingview-widget
npm ERR!     react-tradingview-widget@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/alex/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alex/.npm/_logs/2022-09-26T02_27_08_062Z-debug-0.log
```

Then I tried "npm i daisyui --force" I can see the dependency is in my package.json file.
However, when I tried to use it in the  "tailwind.config.js" by inset  `plugins: [require("daisyui")],` into the file, however vscode shows

Could not find a declaration file for module 'daisyui'. '/Users/alex/Maqro-Portal-Frontend/node_modules/daisyui/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/daisyui` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'daisyui';`ts(7016)

then i do npm i --save-dev @types/daisyui, the terminal gives me en error

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-reconciler@0.23.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm WARN     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm WARN     4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm WARN   35 more (@emotion/styled, @mui/base, @mui/icons-material, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-reconciler@0.23.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-reconciler
npm WARN   react-reconciler@"^0.23.0" from @react-pdf/renderer@2.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-reconciler@0.23.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-reconciler
npm WARN     react-reconciler@"^0.23.0" from @react-pdf/renderer@2.1.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.8.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.8.0" from @mui/system@5.8.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.8.1" from @mui/material@5.8.1
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   34 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-tradingview-widget
npm ERR!   react-tradingview-widget@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-tradingview-widget
npm ERR!     react-tradingview-widget@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/alex/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alex/.npm/_logs/2022-09-26T02_33_39_239Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting your node_modules folder and your package-lock.json, then do

`npm install daisyui`

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions

1. delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-install the `DaisyUI` or [`react-daisyui`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-daisyui?activeTab=readme)
2. You can try to install DaisyUi with version as  `npm i daisyui@0.1.10`